# Is there a site like fast.ai or deeplearning.ai but for machine learning instead of deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for a summary of the pros and cons of different machine learning models in practise.

Something that includes:
- How the model works
- What kinds of outliers will be misrepresented by the model
- Effect of different parameters in each model on speed/performance

Comment: I doubt that this exists, I guess everything you will find is a summary [like this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-tour-of-machine-learning-algorithms/). If you look at [how Wikipedia outlines Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_machine_learning), I have the feeling a *comprehensive* summary would still be overwhelming. I would suggest to look into more specific summaries like *Supervised Learning* or, like you already mentioned, *Deep Learning*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment due to low reputation, but as a *comprehensive* summary I'd recommend [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) by Hastie et. al. It reviews most current state-of-the-art ML methods, together with the classics, is free of charge (big thanks to the authors!), and even has a nice accompanying [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ElemStatLearn/ElemStatLearn.pdf).

It's probably not the source you've expected, but is really a nice place to start, especially for practitioners.